# Vuetify Dialog with Data from Remote API

Tags: axios, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have a number of pages within my Vue3 App that that when a Grid Row element is clicked, the element passes a parameter to a Axios command and then I want a common Dialog to display (all the same data/api endpoint etc).

I have gone in circles all day and cant work it out.  Between different versions and my lack of skills I have gone no where.  I THINK i came close with a Vue modal, have I have seen a few that use other frameworks, but nothing has been able to get me any code thats close to usable for what I am after.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/

Can I get some pointers in the right directions please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe think of having a dialog component inside your app's root component, and have the v-model controlling it as well as the data it displays in a global store like [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/). This way any component in your app can import the store giving it the ability to trigger the dialog and also feed it whatever data should be displayed.

Example where a component wants to trigger a dialog to display some user data:

**App.vue (root component)**

`<Dialog>` placed here so it can be overlayed on any view in the app displayed by `<router-view />`

```html
<template>
  <Dialog />
  <router-view />
</template>
```

**/store/users.js (Pinia store)**

Stores the value of the v-dialog's v-model as `dialog` and dialog content as `selectedUser`

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useUserStore = defineStore('users', {
  state: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    selectedUser: {},
  }),
  actions: {
    openDialogWithUser(user) {
      this.selectedUser = user;
      this.dialog = true;
    },
  },
});
```

**Dialog.vue**

Imports store data to set v-dialog's v-model and content

```js
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
    <!-- display data here -->
    <div>{{ selectedUser }}</div>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useUserStore } from '@/store/users.js';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

const store = useUserStore();

const { dialog, selectedUser } = storeToRefs(store);
</script>
```

**Component.vue** (can be any component in your app)

Calls the store's action to open the dialog and passes in user data to be displayed

```js
<template>
  <div>
    Click to open Dialog
    <div
      v-for="user in users"
      :key="user.id"
      @click="openDialog(user)" <!-- call store action with clicked user -->
      class="user"
    >
      <div>user name: {{ user.name }}</div>
      <div>user description: {{ user.description }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useUserStore } from '@/store/users.js';

const users = ref([ ... ]); // placeholder user data, replace with your fetched API data

const store = useUserStore();

const openDialog = (user) => {
  store.openDialogWithUser(user);
};
</script>
```

[working sandbox example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-qmlkiv?file=src%2Fstore%2Fusers.js,src%2Fviews%2FHome.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FDialog.vue,src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev)

Comment: hay @yoduh , i got this working as a modal, thank you very much.  However when I try to have Axios get the data on load of the modal, i cant make this work.  Do you have any pointers please?  example json source: https://dummyjson.com/products

Comment: and why didnt my @yoduh work to highlight your name?

Comment: to confirm, in that dummyjson, you can do https://dummyjson.com/products/1 to get ID1

Answer (score 0):

I think you're creating a modal component that can be used anywhere in the project, and ideally, it should be a method. I believe [@unoverlays/vue](https://unoverlays.vercel.app/en/vue/) can help you with that.

```html
<!-- overlay.vue -->
<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue'
import { useOverlayMeta } from '@unoverlays/vue'
const props = defineProps({
  content: String,
})
// Get overlay information from useOverlayMeta
const { visible, resolve, reject } = useOverlayMeta({
  // Duration of the overlay animation to avoid premature component destruction
  animation: 1000,
})
</script>

<template>
  <!-- Customized modal using vuetify -->
  <v-dialog v-model="visible">
    <div>{{ content }}</div>

    <button @click="resolve(`${content}:confirmed`)"> click confirm </button>
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

You can use the `defineOverlay` method to convert the component into a modal dialog in Javascript / Typescript, which allows you to call it.

```
import { defineOverlay } from '@unoverlays/vue'
import OverlayComponent from './overlay.vue'

// Convert to imperative callback
const callback = defineOverlay(OverlayComponent)
// Call the component and get the value of the resolve callback
const value = await callback({ content: 'callbackOverlay' })
// value === "callbackOverlay:confirmed"
```

You can register Unoverlays globally, which will inherit the application context for all popups.

```
// main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import unoverlay from '@unoverlays/vue'

const app = createApp({})
app.use(unoverlay)
```

or you can also pass in the context with finer control.

```
import { renderOverlay } from '@unoverlays/vue'
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue-demi'
import Component from './overlay.vue'

// in your setup method
const { appContext } = getCurrentInstance()!
renderOverlay(Component, {
  props: {},
  appContext
})
```